# Run program on times specified in database

Tags: postgresql, debian

**Project** (only for context)

I am currently developing a booking solution where customers can book resources from a webapp by dragging events into a calendar (also able to move, edit, delete) in a google calendar like fashion. The persistence layer of my webapp stores the reservations in a table on postgres 9.3 with an start and end (as `timestamp with timezone` because the users/customers will be in different timezones). This part workes fine. The webapp runs on Debian and works with Play! written with scala if that matters.

**Problem**

Now the problem I am trying to solve is that on the start time of the reservation a program needs to be run to configure client access to the resource (and on the stop time as well to disable access). Also it needs to get parameters passed or at least get informed why it was started (to make it clear if multiple resources are booked at this time) somehow. The configuration program will be written in java or scala if that matters and will run on a different machine than the database.

*EDIT:* It does not need a GUI or anything it just needs to get run.

**What I already read**

I read something about `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` but am not sure about how I would go about using this to start my program. I am very new to the whole topic of databases. Is this even the right way to go?

**tl;dr**

I try to run a program on times stored in a postgres database and dont know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an external cron job or other periodic task scheduler that queries the table and decides whether something needs to run. If you're in Java/Scala you could do it with a simple Thread that sleeps during idle periods. Or whatever timing framework Play! includes internally - which looks like [asynchronous jobs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/jobs) in Play! 1.2; there'll be something similar in 2.x if you're using that. This answer might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16982421/398670

You can have the program sleep for short periods then poll for new notifications on a PostgreSQL connection and re-check the schedule when it gets a notification. When the schedule table changes in the database, have a trigger send a NOTIFY so the polling client knows to update its copy.

The polling program can modify its sleep intervals so it sleeps until the exact time that an event is supposed to occur, at which point it launches the specified command.

PgJDBC doesn't offer a callback when a NOTIFY comes in, so you can't sleep until the next event or until woken by callback. You'll have to do short sleeps and then wake up to poll for notifications using [`PGConnection.getNotifications()`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/PGConnection.html#getNotifications())

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to tell me with the linked question and the timing in Play because it souldnt be the webapp polling the database or should it? Maybe there is a bit of misunderstanding here because the configuration program wont be written with play. But all in all I am taking from this that a polling mechanism cant be avoided in my situation. Do other DBMSs implement a callback with JDBC so this could work without polling?

Comment: @mgttlinger The polling required for `LISTEN` in PgJDBC is only on the client side. You don't have to hit the database server, though for most reliable results you can send an empty query (`""`) to force a client/server round trip and buffer flush. See the PgJDBC documentation. This polling is cheap so you can do it on a short sleep cycle to react to changes quickly. As for what does the polling - that's up to you. You can use whatever you want, whatever fits well into your app. Shell script running from `psql` with `cron`, separate java daemon, whatever you like. In-webapp is just one option.

Comment: Just wanted to add the Link to the [documentation of postgres jdbc Listen/Notify](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/listennotify.html)